# .htaccess - Does the order of code blocks play a role?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

does the order of code blocks in .htaccess play an important role? I found similar questions but they were only about the order of different rewrite rules, not about different htaccess modules. Should I change the order my my 3 blocks (security headers, https rewrite rule, gzip)?

I have this code:

```
# Extra Security Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header set Strict-Transport-Security max-age=17280000
    Header set Referrer-Policy no-referrer
    Header set Feature-Policy "camera 'none'; microphone 'none'; geolocation 'none'; payment 'none';"
    Header set Content-Security-Policy
    "
        default-src 'self';
        style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
        font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
        frame-src ’self‘ https://www.youtube.com/ https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/ https://www.google.com/;
        script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com;
        img-src ’self‘ data: https://img.youtube.com https://i1.ytimg.com https://i.ytimg.com https://i9.ytimg.com https://s.ytimg.com https://www.google-analytics.com www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net;
        connect-src https://www.google-analytics.com www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net
    "
</IfModule>

# https www redirect
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# gzip
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/shtml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The order of these "blocks" is not relevant since they are independent. You should however consider to place those configuration aspects in the actual http server's host configuration instead of using such distributed configuration files, _unless you have no access to the real configuration because you are using a cheap web space provider..._

Comment: I mostly work for small clients who are on shared webhosting servers where I can only configure this in .htaccess.

Comment: It certainly works. The issue is that is slows down the server quite a lot and it makes debugging much more error prone. If you have multiple clients, then why don't you operate an own instance?